# How to close nonmodal overlay dialog from outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to be able to toggle an overlay dialog box using a button outside. The problem is that when the overlay dialog opens it blocks mouse access to the button.  Can one mimic the Bootstrap modal response without using its data- classes? Is it possible to get around of this modal behavior using CSS, jQuery or javaScript? Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
    .nonmodals {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 10000;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body onload="HideModals()">
<a type="button" onclick="ToggleReserve()" class="btn btn-primary">Toggle  Overlay</a>
<div id="reserveform" class="nonmodals" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">The Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     <div>
        <h3>Hello!</h3>
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn- primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </form>
    </div>  
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function ToggleReserve() {
        $("#reserveform").toggle(500);
    }                
    function HideModals() {
        $('.nonmodals').css('display', 'none');
    }    
  </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sure why you'd want to do that, but the css you can use to do it is

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Add it to your "reserve form" div. Any mouse clicks will go through the div to what lies beneath. If you need some clicks not to fall through, you will have to re-set the pointer-events style for those elements.